# Which appium version support mac os 10.12.5

Tags: xcode, macos, android-studio, appium

I have mac with latest version Sierra(10.12.5)  and i want to install appium in my mas system so guyz can you please suggest me which version of appium, xcode, xcode command line tool, and Android studio will support and it will work properly  because I have installed appium 1.5.3 version but it is not catch my system and device too.

so please is if any body have knowledge  about that then suggest me .

Answer (score 0):

I use:

- appium - [1.6.4 (command line)](https://github.com/appium/appium)
- Xcode / Command Line Tools - 8.3.2
- Android Studio - 2.3.1 (with updated SDK)
- java client - [v5.0.0-BETA8](https://github.com/appium/java-client)